# Read Text from file and put the in the TextBox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I got the data from a text file as follows:

> KILL
>   MAD
>   JOG
>     JUG

From the above data I want to put the text "Kill" in Textbox 1, the text "MAD" in textbox 2, the text "JOG" in the textbox 3, and "JUG" in the textbox 4
The following screenshot
[Click Here](http://prntscr.com/5686j7)

So, anyone can help me ?

Comment: Yes we can. Can you show your attempt and exactly where your stuck?

Comment: Use a `ListBox` or a `DataGridView` instead.

Comment: iam sorry, i forgot to input the Link !
can you help with Code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
TextBox1.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0)
TextBox2.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1)
TextBox3.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2)
TextBox4.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(3)
```

You could also use the indexer(`f.e. lines(0)`) of the array instead of `ElementAtOrDefault`. But the latter has the advantage that it doesn't throw an exception if there are fewer elements.

However, i would use a `ListBox` instead or a single `TextBox` with `Multiline=true`:

```
TextBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put a seprator between values stored in file, then you can read it as below:

```
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")

Dim strArray() as String = fileReader .Split("|") 'change the | by your separator

TextBox1.Text = strArray(0)
TextBox2.Text = strArray(1)
TextBox3.Text = strArray(2)
```

Comment: you should make a loop that start from zero and ends to strArray().Lentgh -1

Comment: I know how but your answer doesnt reflect this. Its possible that at strArray(2) is nothing and hence would fail...